# Getting error while while adding contracts-pallet

Tags: contract, pallet

```
 --- stderr
 Compiling node-template-runtime v3.0.0 (/root/substrate-node-template/runtime)
```

error: expected one of: `Pallet`, `Call`, `Storage`, `Event`, `Config`, `Origin`, `Inherent`, `ValidateUnsigned`
--> /root/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:350:33
|
350 |         Contracts: pallet_contracts::{Module, Call, Config, Storage, Event},
|                                       ^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://discord.com/channels/722223075629727774/759061709192298557/854397102792638494) in the Polka Dot Discord server from someone at Parity Technologies, it seems that `Module` is deprecated in favor of `Pallet`. This tutorial will probably need to be re-written for the new syntax.